# substring increment in a string

Tags: c, string

Suppose I have a string value "110099" and I need to increment the substring value "00" in steps of x until y and wrap to zero , if x =10 and y=90 i.e "111099","112099" ... and after "119099" the string value is "110099". Can anyone please help how do I start with. thanks for your time.

EDIT:
Changed the question to be generic.

Comment: One option is to just do long addition (add, check for carry, and continue to the next digit). Another option is to store as int, and convert to number every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take the substring you want to increment.
2. Cast it to integer values.
3. increment by 10 and then %100.
4. Cast back to string.
5. Replace it back in your original string.

   *Code is pretty simple.*

Answer (score 2):

Since you only need to check and change a single digit, I would do it directly in the string representation.

Perhaps something like this:

```
#define INCR_INDEX 2

int increment(char *value)
{
  if( value[INCR_INDEX] == '9' )
  {
    value[INCR_INDEX] = '0';
    return 1;
  }
  ++value[INCR_INDEX];
  return 0;
}
```

The above does the increment, and returns `1` if it wrapped, `0` if it didn't.

This is 100% safe with respect to encodings, C guarantees that the hosting environment encodes the decimal digits in adjacent locations, so `++` on a `char` holding any digit less than `9` will always generate the next digit.

Answer (score 1):

The specification of`"00"` is misleading as it is only the third character in the string that needs to change (the second `0` in `"00"` never changes). It is possible to increment a `char` so if the third `char` is not equal to `9` then increment it otherwise set it to `0`:

```
char a[] = "110099";

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    a[2] = ('9' == a[2]) ? '0' : a[2] + 1;
    printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

See demo at https://ideone.com/uMyfo.

Answer (score 0):

Just increment the third "digit":

```
char s[] = "110099";

for ( ; ; )
{
    printf("Current value: %s\n", s);

    if (s[2] == '9') { s[2] = '0'; break; }
    ++s[2];
}
```

This assumes that your character set stores the numerals contiguously in ascending range.

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void incDigit(char* str, size_t pos)
{
  if (++str[pos] > '9')
    str[pos] = '0';
}

int main(void)
{
  char str[] = "110099";
  int i;

  printf("Original:   %s\n", str);

  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    printf("Adding 1... ");
    incDigit(str, 2);
    printf("%s\n", str);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/M0A9C)):

```
Original:   110099
Adding 1... 111099
Adding 1... 112099
Adding 1... 113099
Adding 1... 114099
Adding 1... 115099
Adding 1... 116099
Adding 1... 117099
Adding 1... 118099
Adding 1... 119099
Adding 1... 110099
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear how flexible you want this to be. A solution to your current question could be the following function.

```
void increment(char str*) {
    str[2]++;
    if (str[2]>'9') str[2]='0';
}
```

Test:

```
char str[] = "110099";
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    increment(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Result:

```
111099
112099
113099
114099
115099
116099
117099
118099
119099
110099
111099
112099
```